# How can I have my own settings menu in my windows application?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have created a windows service to perform certain task on regular basis. Now I want users to change few parameters by themselves. So user should be able to right click on the service and click on settings and a form should appear. On save button all the values should be saved to the app.exe.config file.

Does anyone have any tutorial or any reference website?

Comment: As far as I know, you could only use commandline-style parameters in the service properties dialog. Why not make a small application to modify your config file?

Answer (score 2):

1) Users NEVER right click on a Windows Service. WS are by definition programs that run in background.

2) You can create a service controller, a windows form application that interacts with the service and sends commands like pause, start, stop, etc. Implement your user interface in such controller.

You can start reading this post:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.100).aspx

Good luck!